# ECS containers securely routed via API Gateway not returning but health check on containers is good

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

Okay so this is going to be a long one, but I want to make sure I explain. I am trying to do a proof of concept that we can deploy micro services via ECS that are exposed using API Gateway so we can leverage the lambda authorisers and cognito.

To achieve this I have been following this guide on [Medium](https://medium.com/adobetech/deploy-microservices-using-aws-ecs-fargate-and-api-gateway-1b5e71129338)

However once I deploy my gateway I am faced with the following error:

```
Cannot GET /node-demo
```

Let me go through the basics, I have a basic express application like so:

```
const express = require('express')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  return response.json({
    data: {
      message: `API is functional`,
    },
  })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:10.16.3

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY index.js .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This docker image has been pushed to ECR, I have created a Task Definition with an environment variable `PORT => 80`

Created a service on my cluster which is working fine. Then created an ALB with a target group that points to my containers, these come back healthy!

[image: Healthy ALB targets]

And I route to these targets with the following:

[image: Routing]

My NLB then points to the ALB and I have allowed the correct IPs on the ALB so we can get to it through the security group. Both IPs in the NLB target group are healthy

Created a VPC link in API Gateway and then created a resource like the below:

[image: API]

I then deploy hit the URL with `/node-demo` at the end and get the initial error above. Either the guide has a mistake or I've done something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Add suggest making a few tests to isolate the problem. Can you make a direct call to the ECS internal IP? If it succeeds then the issue is with routing. Also, check your security groups and make sure the ports and IPs/subnets are whitelisted.

Comment: Problem with hitting the internal IP is where do I do that form?

Comment: Why do you have both ALB and NLB? Woudn't it be better to have API Gateway -> NLB -> ECS service?

Comment: I'm only going from that guide, I'll give that a go!

Comment: Ah I remember why, the ALB means I can have multiple target groups that I can then route under different urls i.e. /test /demo etc

Comment: Please expand on this: "I have allowed the correct IPs on the ALB so we can get to it through the security group". What IPs have you allowed exactly? The NLB will pass through the caller's IP address. The ALB won't see the traffic as coming from the NLB's IP, I believe it will see it as coming from some API Gateway server's IP. You will most likely need to open up the ALB to all IPs.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain, but if you look at the medium article and search "Setup the Integration between NLB and ALB" That section is what your referring too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good and bad news,

Good news, I've solved the problem.

Bad news, it's super simple

Just needed to add a route to the express application,

`/node-demo`